Slope coefficients of Continuous Change Detection and Classification (CCDC) in GEE
I’m using the Continuous Change Detection and Classification (CCDC) algorithm in Google Earth Engine to extract slope coefficients from my analysis. However, I’m encountering an error when trying to extract the slope values. Slope error Image (Error)
Image.arrayGet: Input band 'RED_coefs' has 2 dimensions, but 'position' has 1 bands.

My script is:
// Run CCD. 
var ccdResults = 
ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.Ccdc(ccdParams); 
print(ccdResults);


var palettes = require('users/gena/packages:palettes'); 

// Select time of break and change probability array images. 
var change = ccdResults.select('tBreak'); 
var changeProb = ccdResults.select('changeProb'); 
// Set the time range we want to use and get as mask of 
// places that meet the condition. 
var start = 2018; 
var end = 2021; 
var mask = change.gt(start).and(change.lte(end)).and(changeProb.eq(1)); 

// / Select the NDVI coefficients
var RED_coefs = ccdResults.select('RED_coefs')
//// Print the NDVI coefficients to understand its structure
print('RED Coefficients:', RED_coefs);

// Extract the slope coefficient (assuming it is the second coefficient)
var slope = RED_coefs.arraySlice(1, 1, 2);

// Since arrayFlatten expects one list of names, handle this manually if needed
var slopeBand = slope.arrayGet([0]);

// Print the slope to verify
print('Slope:', slopeBand);

The full of my script is the link below:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/cd567e64ab0fac523bcec2e6d9f843cd

It looks like your output of arraySlice is a 2 dimensions array. arrayGet takes an image with scalar bands as many as there are dimensions in the input image (i.e, 2 in your case). See doc here. Hence, you can replace line 44
var slopeBand = slope.arrayGet([0])

with
var slopeBand = arrayGet(ee.Image([0,0]));

Note that this will get you the element at axis-0 position-0 and axis-1 position 0. However, your slope arrayimage contains one raw (elements on axis-0) in some pixels and many rows in other pixels (numbers are different from pixel to pixel). Which is why your code comment noted that they didn't use arrayFlatten. So in short, arrayGet(ee.Image([0,0])) will get you the first element only, and while getting each element as a band might be difficult and outside the scope of the question, it might also be helpful to get the last element too using arrayGet(ee.Image([-1,0])). Inspecting different pixels using the code here  should show the case!
